# Initializing unordered map from a member function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, stl

I have the following program which has an unordered map as a member variable. I want to initialize the map from a member function, which I have added `initialize_resource_map`.

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <thread>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

template < class socket_type > class MyClass {

    std::unordered_map < std::string, std::unordered_map < std::string,
    std::function < void (std::shared_ptr < typename MyClass < socket_type >::Response >,
    std::shared_ptr < typename MyClass < socket_type >::Request >) > >>resource;

    class Request: public std::ostream
    {


    };

    class Response
    {


    };
    void initialize_resource_map(MyClass server, std::string pattern,
                                 std::function <void (std::shared_ptr < typename MyClass <socket_type>::Response> response_func,
                                 std::shared_ptr < typename MyClass < socket_type >::Request> request_ptr))
    {
        server.resource[pattern]["GET"] =
                        [&server] (response_func, request_ptr) 
        {
                        std::string number = request_ptr->path_match[1];
                        *response_func << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: " << number.length() << "\r\n\r\n" << number;
        }
    };
};


int main()
{


    return 0;
}
```

I am compiling it using the following command.

```
g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp  -o test
```

I get the following errors.

```
test.cpp:29:106: error: template argument 1 is invalid
                                  std::shared_ptr < typename MyClass < socket_type >::Request> request_ptr))
                                                                                                          ^
test.cpp:29:106: error: template argument 1 is invalid
test.cpp:29:106: error: template argument 1 is invalid
test.cpp:29:106: error: template argument 1 is invalid
test.cpp:29:106: error: template argument 1 is invalid
test.cpp:28:39: error: ‘std::function’ is not a type
                                  std::function <void (std::shared_ptr < typename MyClass <socket_type>::Response> response_func,
                                       ^
test.cpp:28:48: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
                                  std::function <void (std::shared_ptr < typename MyClass <socket_type>::Response> response_func,
                                                ^
test.cpp: In member function ‘void MyClass<socket_type>::initialize_resource_map(MyClass<socket_type>, std::string, int)’:
test.cpp:32:36: error: ‘response_func’ has not been declared
                         [&server] (response_func, request_ptr) 
                                    ^
test.cpp:32:51: error: ‘request_ptr’ has not been declared
                         [&server] (response_func, request_ptr) 
                                                   ^
test.cpp: In lambda function:
test.cpp:34:46: error: ‘request_ptr’ was not declared in this scope
                         std::string number = request_ptr->path_match[1];
                                              ^
test.cpp:35:26: error: ‘response_func’ was not declared in this scope
                         *response_func << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: " << number.length() << "\r\n\r\n" << number;
                          ^
test.cpp: In member function ‘void MyClass<socket_type>::initialize_resource_map(MyClass<socket_type>, std::string, int)’:
test.cpp:37:5: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘}’ token
     };
```

I am new to template programming. what am I doing wrong? This is the original code, that initalizes the unordered map that I am trying to convert to a member function. In case that helps

```
int main()
{
    typedef Server < HTTP > HttpServer;
    HttpServer server(8080, 1); 

    server.resource["^/match/([0-9]+)$"]["GET"] =
                [&server] (std::shared_ptr < HttpServer::Response > response, std::shared_ptr < HttpServer::Request > request) {
                std::string number = request->path_match[1];
                *response << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: " << number.length() << "\r\n\r\n" << number;
    };  




    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could use some typedefs in there. It would probably make your error easier to spot as well.

Comment: typedefs for namespaces you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some punctuation is missing on this line:

```
std::shared_ptr < typename MyClass < socket_type >::Request> request_ptr))
```

This should be

```
std::shared_ptr < typename MyClass < socket_type >::Request> request_ptr)>)
```

I am a big fan of `emacs`'s automatic highlighting of matching open/close parenthesis/braces/brackets, etc... It made this typo very obvious.

The other error is on this line:

```
    server.resource[pattern]["GET"] =
                    [&server] (response_func, request_ptr)
```

Neither `response_func`, nor `request_ptr` are defined. They're only named parameter types used in the preceding `std::function`'s signature. Looks to me like this might be because you showed stripped down code, and not the full code, in your question. Your full code is likely defining these variables. If that's not the case, you will have to figure this one out yourself, since nobody else will be able to tell you where these variables should be defined. This is not clear from the shown code.

EDIT: based on the additional information included in the question, the remaining issue with the member function is that it should be:

```
void initialize_resource_map(MyClass server, std::string pattern,
                             std::function <void (std::shared_ptr < typename MyClass <socket_type>::Response> response_func,
                          std::shared_ptr < typename MyClass < socket_type >::Request> request_ptr)>)
{
    server.resource[pattern]["GET"] =
                    [&server] (std::shared_ptr < typename MyClass <socket_type>::Response> response_func, std::shared_ptr < typename MyClass < socket_type >::Request> request_ptr)
    {
                    std::string number = request_ptr->path_match[1];
                    *response_func << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: " << number.length() << "\r\n\r\n" << number;
    };
}
```

The lambda's parameters need to remain, as is; and a semicolon was misplaced.

As a side note, the complicated types makes the end result a bit messy. That's quite common, and `typedef`s do wonders to clean this up. Doesn't this look much, much cleaner:

```
typedef std::shared_ptr <Response> response_func_t;

typedef std::shared_ptr <Request> request_ptr_t;

void initialize_resource_map(MyClass server, std::string pattern,
                 std::function <void (response_func_t response_func,
                                      request_ptr_t request_ptr)>)
{
    server.resource[pattern]["GET"] =
        [&server] (response_func_t response_func,
                   request_ptr_t request_ptr)
        {
            std::string number = request_ptr->path_match[1];
            *response_func << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: " << number.length() << "\r\n\r\n" << number;
        };
}
```

HOWEVER, this is still undefined behavior, and will likely result in a crash, even though this compiles. The lambda captures `server` by reference, but the reference is locally-scoped, so the referenced variable will go out of scope as soon as the member function returns, and the captured variable will no longer be valid.

But this does solve the compilation error. You will have to figure out the scoping issue on your own.

Comment: Updated. The compilation error is solvable, but, as noted, you have a major bug in the design of the member function. That's something you will have to solve on your own.